# Statistical query to loop through different date periods

Tags: postgresql, loops, statistics

I have a massive query log table in postgresql. I have been asked to get statistical data from it, but the table is sooooo massive. It has about ~170000000 rows in it.

So I've been asked a statistical data for last 6 months, that will have count of services for each day.

The issue is that since the table is so big, it will take forever to get this data.

Here's the current query I use:

```
SELECT ql.query_time::timestamp::date,count(ql.query_name),ql.query_name 
FROM query_log ql
WHERE ql.query_time BETWEEN '2017-12-20 14:00:00.000'::timestamp AND '2018-06-20 14:00:00.000'::timestamp AND success=TRUE
GROUP BY ql.query_time::timestamp::date, ql.query_name;
```

Please make proposals how to make this query faster and and effective. I want to save the output into the CSV.
I've been thinking on looping through each day for past 6 months but dont know how to do it.

OH, ql.query_time is indexed.

Thx!

Comment: You probably need an index on `query_time`. With the appropriate index, query time will only depend on the result size, not on the table size.

Comment: Hi! As I mentioned, query_time is indexed, also query_name is indexed.
I ran explain for the SQL query and the result is:
"GroupAggregate  (cost=17724584.26..18878565.49 rows=40849525 width=35)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=17724584.26..17885424.80 rows=64336217 width=35)"
"        Sort Key: ((query_time)::date), query_name"
"        ->  Seq Scan on query_log ql  (cost=0.00..5862068.49 rows=64336217 width=35)"
"              Filter: (success AND (query_time >= '2017-12-20 14:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (query_time <= '2018-06-20 14:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"

Comment: I see. Then maybe `CREATE INDEX ON query_log (query_time) WHERE success;`. If that doesn't do the trick (and your table statistics are accurate), then you'll probably have to live with the sequential scan because it is the fastest option.